# how to activate page with out creating version history data in aem

Tags: aem, aem-6

How to activate Page with out create versionHistory data Jcr:system Level

/jcr:system/jcr:versionStorage/b6/7f/7c/b67f7c22-678f-4696-9022-80a21665aed5/1.0

i don’t want create versions like 1.0, 1.1,1.2….. when i am activate page

[How to programatically delete revisions of a page in CQ5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30773706/how-to-programatically-delete-revisions-of-a-page-in-cq5)

Answer (score 0):

One of the options in the Version Manager is set by default to create versions on activation.  But you can change it to false, and it will no longer create them on activation.  See https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/deploy/configuring/version-purging.html

> Version Manager
>
> In addition to explicit purging by means of the purge tool, the
>   Version Manager can be configured to purge old versions when new
>   versions are created.
>
> To configure the Version Manager, create a configuration for:
>
> ```
> PID com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.VersionManagerImpl
> ```
>
> The following options are available:
>
> ```
> versionmanager.createVersionOnActivation (Boolean, default: true)
> whether to create a version when pages are activated.
> A version is created unless the replication agent is configured to suppress creation of versions, which is honoured by the Version
> ```
>
> Manager
>       A version is only created if the activation happens on a paths that is contained in versionmanager.ivPaths (see below).

Also see https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/DisableVersioning.html

Comment: in My workflow i have two models 1)create version model 2) activate page workflow
by create version workflow i am creating versions like 1,0,1,,1,1,2 this one is fine.
again i m using activation page model to activate page author to publish instance.

in that it will creating versions 1,0,1,,1,1,2…….. i don’t need to create versions in this model.

in workflow only one time i need to create versions .

is it possible particular activate page model i need to disable versions.

Comment: thanks you, how to do for specific project this configuration

Comment: i don't want affect this configuration remaining projects